# Mongodb interrupted while reindexing

Tags: mongodb, shell, indexing, database

I have a collection with about 3,000,000 entries that I need to reindex. This whole thing began when I tried to add a 2d index. To do this, I created an ssh tunnel, opened the mongo shell and tried to use ensureIndex. I'm in a place with a somewhat unreliable internet connection, and an hour in it ended up breaking the pipe. I then tunneled back in, opened the mongo shell and tried to look at the number of indexes using getIndexes; the new index I created showed up, but I wasn't confident it had finished, so I decided to use reIndex. In retrospect, this was stupid. The pipe broke again. Now when I open the shell and try to issue getIndexes, the shell doesn't respond.

So what should I do? Do I need to repair my database? Can I issue reIndex when I have a more reliable internet connection? Is there a way to issue reIndex without keeping the shell open, but without doing it in the background and having it take eons? (I'll check the mongod shell options to see if I can find anything, then check the node.js mongo api so I can try running something as a service on server)

And also, if I end up running reIndex as a service on the server, is there any way to check if it's working? The most frustrating part of this right now is I have no idea if my database is ok, if reIndex is still running, etc. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a problem. Mongo runs commands and only stops them if you explicitly kill the operation (db.killOp()).

You do not need to wait for the index operation to finish!

Comment: Awesome! Just checked it again; everything looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the connection problems, try using the `screen` command.
It enables you to create a "persistent" screen - not in the way of disk persistence, but in the means of connection-loss.

Comment: The screen command is [this](https://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/linux-the-screen-command-a-must-for-ssh/), right?